# Latte dock on Kubuntu does not auto started any more

Tags: kubuntu, plasma, latte-dock

I had installed [latte-dock](/questions/tagged/latte-dock) *ver. 0.8.9* and it worked fine before. However, due to some mistaken configurations during applying new [plasma](/questions/tagged/plasma) look and feel themes I decided to uninstall Latte and the reinstall it again.

Currently, Latte does not be started automatically on login. I always have to press `ALT + Space` to invoke the search app and start it manually.

I have tried the following:

1. Uninstall Latte then reinstall it after restarting the computer.
2. Check/Uncheck **Enable autostart during startup** from Latte Dock Settings.
   [image]
3. From the terminal I checked out `latte-dock --replace` and I got the following output

```
Invalid Context= "animations" line for icon theme:  "/home/x/.local/share/icons/Oranchelo-Beka/animations/22/"
Invalid Context= "panel" line for icon theme:  "/home/x/.local/share/icons/Oranchelo-Beka/panel/22/"
Invalid Context= "panel" line for icon theme:  "/home/x/.local/share/icons/Oranchelo-Beka/panel/16/"
Invalid Context= "status" line for icon theme:  "/home/x/.local/share/icons/Oranchelo-Beka/status/scalable/"
Icon theme "gnome" not found.
```

*where `x` is the username*

4. Also I tried to add autostart entry from system settings[image]

#### Update

The following is a screen shot from **KSystemlog** where it shows some warnings during starting **Latte**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This question is pretty old now, but I just had a similar problem.  My situation was also self-inflicted (accidentally deleting `~/.config` !!!)  The Latte Dock had been previously installed and working.

The fix for me was to clear the Latte cache.  Running `latte-dock --help` shows the command options: `--cc` or `--clear-cache`:

```
latte-dock --cc
```

After that, the Latte Dock was just fine.  It now loads during session startup.

P.S.  I also see a lot of `Invalid Context=...` messages for icons.  They're annoying, but seem harmless.  I suspect it's just some installed icons (for gnome) that aren't Plasma-friendly.  In fact, I came across this post while looking for a way to eliminate those messages!